# PhpStorm Deployment menu greyed out

Tags: ide, phpstorm

I've added a server in PhpStorm deployment settings but the Tools -> Deployment -> Upload to menu is still greyed out.

Answer (score 148):

You need to specify a deployment path mapping in your server. Even if it's just the root path, you need to enter /. PhpStorm doesn't do it automatically.

Go to your server in deployment settings, click the 'Mappings' tab and enter slash (or your mapping) in the 'Deployment path on server' field. You don't need to enter a web path. Deployment menu should be ungreyed now.

Comment: When I go to the `mapping` tab I get only a message saying: `Open or create project to configure mapping`, Well, I have my project open of course...

Comment: @Mirko, you're in Default Settings (File -> Default Settings). Go to project settings (File -> Settings), (Build, Execution, Deployment), (Deployment) then Mappings.

Comment: I swear I do not have the `Settings` options but only the `Default Settings` one, PHPStorm 8.0.2 on Yosemite

Comment: @Mirko strange, I can't reproduce at all on on 8.0.3 Windows 7. You better ask in the PhpStorm forums

Comment: Thanks! This answer should be selected as the correct answer for this question!

Answer (score 17):

In version 2019.2, if you dont set the path to / in mapping, it will grayed out.
Previous version, you could leave it blank

Comment: Thanks. I'd just updated from 2018 and imported the settings. Couldn't figure out what was wrong

Answer (score 13):

Also, if your local path (inside mappings configuration) is not your project root, you have to click on the deployable folder in the project tree to enable the menu.

Answer (score 8):

Also, if the Deployment menu is completely missing at the bottom of the context menu, then set up a default server.

Click the server with the check mark to make a server the default option for a project.

[image]

Then you will get this additional menu when you right click on a file, folder, or the project.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered this issue in PyCharm Professional 2022.1.
Since the aforementioned solutions did not work for me, and it took me some time to resolve, I am providing the solution I found.

Clicking on Tools -> Deployment -> upload to servername was not working for me no matter what I tried.

However, I could **right-click** on the **main project folder** (on the left of the PyCharm window, where the project folder/file structure is visible). This right-click opens a menu, where there is an option for **deployment** -> **upload to servername**.
Once I clicked this, not only it worked, but the classical way (Tools -> Deployment -> upload to  ) ceased to be grayed out also.

Answer (score 0):

If deployment was available and suddenly no longer works, confirm that your credentials didn't get wiped from the deployment settings (Connection tab).

Answer (score 0):

If any of these answers don't help, because you can't even see the server menu, you probably have the `Remote Hosts Access` plugin disabled.

Go to settings, go to the plugins, and enable `Remote Hosts Access`.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the following options are enabled in settings(Ctrl+Alt+S). It goes uncheck if Php Storm crashes. Check the below options and restart the editor.

[image: Plugins list]

This works for ver 2017.2.1
Also, check Windows->Store current layout as the default just to make sure in the future you can restore the layout.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible the opened file in the editor belongs to a External Library (bottom of project tree).
These External library files can't be deployed.

Answer (score 0):

If deployment was once available, but it suddenly stops working (for example after an update). Go to Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Deployment.

For me, everything was still there and seemingly configured. So, I clicked on the OK option(even though I had changed nothing) and the deployment option became available again.
[image]